# XML in R: extracting nodes while storing ancestor info

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I've been having difficulty in a webscraping project. My problem is that I need to extract information of a number of nodes while saving information on their ancestor.

For example, if I want to grab all the items inside all the bulleted lists in a wikipedia page I can do this:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

html = GET("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benz_Patent-Motorwagen")
par = htmlParse(html)

xpathSApply(par, "//ul/li", xmlValue)
```

But what I need is for each item to be paired with the number (order) of the ul it came from. My attempt was the following:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(data.table)

html = GET("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benz_Patent-Motorwagen")
par = htmlParse(html)  

dt = data.table(list_number = numeric(0), list_items = character(0))

for(i in 1:length(xpathSApply(par, "//ul"))){

  node = getNodeSet(par, "//ul")[[i]]
  list_items = xpathSApply(node, "/li", xmlValue)

  new = data.table(list_number = i, list_items)

  dt = rbind(dt, new)
}
```

But it didn't work as I expected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It turns out that all that I needed was a single "." in the second xpath to indicate that the query starts from the node extracted from the getNodeSet, and not from the top of the document.

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(data.table)

html = GET("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benz_Patent-Motorwagen")
par = htmlParse(html)  

dt = data.table(list_number = numeric(0), list_items = character(0))

for(i in 1:length(xpathSApply(par, "//ul"))){

  node = getNodeSet(par, "//ul")[[i]]
  list_items = xpathSApply(node, "./li", xmlValue)

  new = data.table(list_number = i, list_items)

  dt = rbind(dt, new)
}
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2009-March/416365.html